# php mysqli creat index error

Tags: php, mysqli

I use PHP mysqli to create a table and index.But I got this error.

I have already run these sql in mysql client and it worked well.

```
$creatTableSql = <<<EOF
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS duplicate_attachment(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    md5 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    filesize INT(11),
    ids TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX duplicate_attachment_id_uindex ON duplicate_attachment (id);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX duplicate_attachment_md5_uindex ON duplicate_attachment (md5);
EOF;
$mysqli->query($creatTableSql);
var_dump($mysqli->error);
```

> string(226) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX duplicate_attachment_id_uindex ON
>   duplicate_attachment (id);' at line 8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a single query but a set of multiple queries.
You should run them one by one.

```
$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS duplicate_attachment(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    md5 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    filesize INT(11),
    ids TEXT NOT NULL
)";
$mysqli->query("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX duplicate_attachment_id_uindex ON duplicate_attachment (id)";
$mysqli->query("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX duplicate_attachment_md5_uindex ON duplicate_attachment (md5)";
```

Comment: You save my life.Thank you so much!